# Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework empty

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

After putting files of Sitecore Framework in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`, running `Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework –ListAvailable`, returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the SIF for a particular user or all users

```
All users - C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
Specific user - C:\Users\<user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

**Note -**

Before copying SIF folder you may need to `Unblock` by right clicking `zip file -> properties -> General tab -> Unblock`

Refer Sitecore [Document](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/B5EF049EEC134F93835097FFD56E0C6A.ashx) here for complete details

Comment: Ok. Than you. Problem in C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86). Missing copy to C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules